# How to make one specific column editable in a Silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight

I am working on a Silverlight business application. In here I am populating a datagrid in a Silverlight child window. Now the problem I am facing is the my datagrid is having four columns but I have make only one column among them as editable and rest three should remain read-only.

How can I achieve it. I can make the whole datagrid editable but not one specific column. Please note the columns are currently auto-generated.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define before hand the name of the columns this will be much easier and require only xaml code

```
<data:Datagrid x:Name="Grid11" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" SelectionMode="Single" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding LocalIndex}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, Mode=TwoWay}"  >
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:SolacomDatagrid>
```

In the above sample the name column is editable but the other 2 are read only. Note I am using binding so for the code behind you might not need to change anything you will simply need to replace the attributes that are bound.

**EDIT**

```
                foreach (DataGridColumn item in DataGrid.Columns)
                {
                       //if(column name condition of column id)
                    item.IsReadOnly = true;
                }
```

This loop should allow you to set all the columns to read-only. I would personally have this event executed in the DataGrid Loaded event because if this is done too early your columns will not exist yet.

Hope this helps,

Comment: @Staindart is there any way it can work with autogeneratecolumns = true, coz tht's the problem right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your XAML you could add the [Editable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.editableattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) attribute to the properties on your object.